# FastColoredTextBox change link color when hovering and back to old color when cursor is leaved

Tags: c#, vb.net, hyperlink, textbox, styles

I have text with different styles. The links use blue, but on hover I want to change it to dark blue, how can I do that? I can't find a simple solution. Also, I can change the link color to other, but when mouse is leaved, the link will not change to the old color.

```
Private Sub txtOutput_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles txtOutput.MouseMove
        Try
            If e.Location.X > 0 And e.Location.Y > 0 Then
                Dim p As FastColoredTextBoxNS.Place = txtOutput.PointToPlace(e.Location)
                If CharIsHyperlink(p) Then
                    txtOutput.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
                Else
                    txtOutput.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Have your tried the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events?

Comment: For use MouseEnter and MouseLeave events, I need know the element, for subscribe to events. But I don't have elements as Link. It is just text with some link styling (by regex).